# How to a Pass Parameter from Endpoint to API Controller

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm new to programing and have been following a tutorial. I have been able to pass a parameter from my View to my Endpoint...as well as from my API Controller to the SQL Server Stored Procedure. The Parameter will get to the Endpoint but isn't passed to the controller...if I manually pass that parameter through when debugging, it will return the correct data to the View. So what I can't seem to figure out is how to pass the parameter from the Endpoint to the controller.

Endpoint:

```
    public async Task<List<GroupModel>> GetGroupById(int groupId)
    {
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await _apiHelper.ApiClient.GetAsync($"/api/FeedGroup/GetGroupById/{groupId}")
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<GroupModel>>();
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);
            }                
        }
```

API Controller:

```
    [HttpGet("GetGroupById/{GroupId:int}")]
    [Route("GetGroupById")]
    public List<GroupModel> GetGroupById(int GroupId)
    {
        int groupId = GroupId;
        return _GroupData.GetGroupById(groupId);
    }
```

Comment: In controller specify argument as part ofthe url: `[HttpGet("GetGroupById/{GroupId:int}")]` In endpoint pass argument as part of the url: `.GetAsync($"/api/FeedGroup/GetGroupById/{groupId}")`

Comment: @Fabio: Thanks for the answer! Those 2 changes have fixed my problem! I've updated the Question to reflect your answer.

Comment: `[Route]` attribute is redundant now.

Answer (score 0):

Also for info, you are calling an Asynchronous method in your controller over a synchronous HttpGet method here. Thats not a good solution.

A better solution would be the following:

```
 [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetGroupById")]
    public async Task<List<GroupModel>> GetGroupById(int GroupId)
    {
        int groupId = GroupId;
        return await _GroupData.GetGroupById(groupId);
    }
```